# how to hidden the column when i reload the page from selected check box using jquery with angular 4?

Tags: jquery, angular, checkbox, jquery-plugins

> I am using Angular 4 when i reload the page that drop down check boxes
>   would be selected based on `local Storage` values but selected columns
>   in the drop down box was not hidden..

Component.ts:
In this component where i have integrated angular 4 with Jquery

```
ngOnInit()
{
$(document).ready(function(){
            //here i checked localstorage values
                var checkedvalues = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("checkedvalues"));
                console.log(checkedvalues);
            //created obj to store check values
                let someObj:any={};
                someObj.checked=[];
            //looped through checkvalues from local storge ad add checked property to its values
                $.each(checkedvalues, function(key, value) {
                  console.log(key,value);
                  $("#" + value).prop('checked', value);
                  console.log($("#" + value));
                });
                            $(".hidecol").click(function(){

                                var id = this.id; 
                                var splitid = id.split("_");
                                var colno = splitid[1];
                                var checked = true;                                        
                                if($(this).is(":checked")){
                                    checked = true;
            //push chekced values in above created array.
                                    someObj.checked.push($(this).attr("id"));
                                    console.log(someObj.checked);
            //add same values in local storage.
                                    localStorage.setItem("checkedvalues", JSON.stringify(someObj.checked));

                                }else{
                                    checked = false;
                                }
                                setTimeout(function(){
                                    if(checked){
                                        $('#drug_table td:nth-child('+colno+')').hide();
                                        $('#drug_table th:nth-child('+colno+')').hide();
                                    } else{
                                        $('#drug_table td:nth-child('+colno+')').show();
                                        $('#drug_table th:nth-child('+colno+')').show();
                                    }

                                }, 500);

                            });
                        });      
}
```

**ang.html:**

In this html where i given action for drop down box.....

```
    <div class="chkdropdown" id="chkdropdown">
              Show and Hide Columns
            <ul>
                 <li>
                   <input type="checkbox" class="hidecol"  id="col_2" />&nbsp;S NO&nbsp;                
                </li>
                <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" class="hidecol"  id="col_3" />&nbsp;DrugName&nbsp;                
               </li>
               <li>
                  <input type="checkbox" class="hidecol"  id="col_4" />&nbsp; Generic Name&nbsp;                  
               </li>
               <li>
                  <input type="checkbox" class="hidecol"  id="col_5" />&nbsp;Generic Combination&nbsp;                    
                </li>
                <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" class="hidecol"  id="col_6" />&nbsp;Dosage &nbsp;              
                  </li>
                  <li>
                      <input type="checkbox" class="hidecol"  id="col_7" />&nbsp;VAT &nbsp;               
                    </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

 <table width="100%" id="drug_table"  border="0"  class="table">
          <thead>
            <tr class="tr_header">
            <th>#</th>
            <th> S.No </th>
<tr><thead><table>
```

**image:**[image: datable images]

Comment: As a suggestion, its is actually a bad practice, using  too much JQuery in Angular Application.

Comment: Do you  have any other idea about that!! @Anoop

Comment: can you elaborate your question

Comment: You need to remove the jquery part. Set some flags on occurring some events, and show or hide the data using ngIf. Its a very simple task and trust me you can code it in Angular less than 10% of your JQuery stuff .

As a beginner I know its hard. You need to atleast learn on ngFor, ngIf, forms, and events in Angular. Simply because your code doesnt use Angular concepts actually

Comment: ok i understood...i dont know how to do that in angular 4 without jquery ??can u guide me!!!!....@ Anoop

Comment: In Angular 4 when i reload the page that drop down check boxes would be already selected based on local Storage but selected columns in the drop down box was not hidden.....@ Aravind

Comment: @Ajith Kumar. You cant finish the task unless enough basics in Angular. I have answered below, pls have a look. And try to solve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set an array of objects, (in each object a property called checked should be there) in localStorage.

Make your component.ts file (say ActivityComponent) like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-activity',
  templateUrl: './activity.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./activity.component.css']
})
export class ActivityComponent implements OnInit {
  checkedvalues: any = [];
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
     this.checkedvalues = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("checkedvalues"));
     console.log(checkedvalues);
  }

}
```

Now you need to iterate the checkedvalues, in the html using *ngFor. 
Upon new feilds are added you can push it to checkedvalues array just like this.checkedvalues.push() and you can iterate it using foreach() to check whether the check box is checked or not.

In html each checkbox need to binded with ngModel as :

```
<input type="checkbox" class="hidecol"[(ngModel)]=checkedvalues[index].checked name="value">
```

More precisely your unordered list can be shortened to

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let checkedvalue of checkedvalues; let i=index;"> 
         <input type="checkbox" class="hidecol"[(ngModel)]=checkedvalue[i].checked name="value">
    </li>
</ul>
```

Now whatever data is stored in localStorage, its state is reflected in html.

You need to import FormsModule to use [(ngModel)] and CommonModule to use ngFor in the module where you declare this component(probably in app.module.ts).

Finally use a `<form>` and place your code inside it, so that upon submitting you can save data in localStorage.

You dont want to depend on jQuery to show and hide data use ngIf like:

`*ngIf="checkedvalue.checked"` will display the html element only its checked state is true.

Learn more on Angular from https://angular.io/

Comment: i have understood but if u don't mine can u alter the code...@Anoop

Comment: Which one? The one I suggested or you posted

Comment: i posted html and component in which you can modify the code!!....@ Anoop Surendran

Comment: Well I can try. But I could understand your task actually. Tell me what you do with that table?

Comment: i have data table table which contains several column and i want the coulmn to be hidden when select the column name in the dropdown check box  and also even if i reload the page those selected column in the drop down box should be hidden.....pls see image this https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hocqp.png

Comment: Okay show me the format of localStorage data checkedvalues

Comment: just show me how it look like. Is it [{'id': '15', 'checked', true}, {'id': '16', 'checked', false}, ...]

Comment: it was like this coming jquery but in angular i have not done anything....

Comment: do u have any idea about it...@ Anoop Surendran